# Groovy - update multi-line string if pattern matches

Tags: string, groovy, multiline

I have a multiline string "change" as follows

```
change = '''apple.txt 
            orange.jpg 
            banana'''
```

i need to write a groovy script if it matches .txt in a line it appends modified line to the multi-line string.

once the script run  here is what i'd like to see

```
modded_change = '''apple.txt 
                   orange.jpg 
                   banana
                   apple.txt.log'''
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel quite sure that there is a 'groovier' way to do this, but this is one option:

```
change?.split("\n").findAll{it ==~ ".*\\.txt"}?.each{ change += "\n${it}.log" }
```